# Import class from another folder

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to the whole C# thing and I'm a bit used to C++ with the header files. So I hope this isn't the dumbest question.

How can I import the `MainWindow.cs` into the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?
I thought I could just use `using MainWindow.cs`

[image: This is the project structure]

Comment: you need to add the **namespace** with a `using`, not the **file-name**. So presumbly something like `using WhateverNamespace`

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Still "could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: As an aside, you probably shouldn't call the other class `MainWindow` as that will clash with the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net you can use any class in the same project, or in any referenced project or dll. You never need to worry about header files. The .Net assemblies themselves contain all the type information needed to use them.

Type disambiguation is done with namespaces, you should typically place types in a namespace like `ProjectName.Folder` I.e.

```
namespace MyProject.Quelldateien.Inc{
    public class MainWindow{
        ...
    }
}
```

In your code file you need to use the full namespace when refering to a type, i.e. `MyProject.Quelldateien.Inc.MainWindow`, or add a using statement at the top of your file:

```
using MyProject.Quelldateien.Inc
namespace MyProject{
    public class MyClass{ 
    ...
    }
}
```

Note that you should usually try to avoid using the same name for classes, since this would require using the full namespace to refer to your type. A common convention is for your name your xaml-classes `MyMainView` and the view model class (containing properties you bind to) as `MyMainViewModel`. And place this in separate folders.

Also note that some refactoring tools can add namespaces automatically, so I almost never write out `using MyProject.Quelldateien.Inc`, I just write my type name, and accept the namespace suggestion by the tool.

Answer (score 1):

in the MainWindow.cs see the namespace. like:

```
namespace Quelldateien.inc
{
    internal class MainWindow
    {
    }
}
```

then use:

```
using Quelldateien.inc;
```